# How do I format output of \theenumi to become uppercase Roman Numeral

Tags: enumerate

I would like to return the item number inside a text string, using upper-case roman numerals. I don't know how to pass that option to \theenumi counter.
The desired output would be:

1. Some text I

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\frame{}

{

\begin{enumerate}

\item  Some text \theenumi  

\end{enumerate}

}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one of the many counter formatting commands on the respective counter: `\Roman{enumi}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\frame{
\begin{enumerate}
\item  Some text \Roman{enumi}
\end{enumerate}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no need to downvote this answer.

Comment: Question is need to change the cross reference for all "enumi" (from Arabic into Roman). But now the answer will work for last  "enumi" (\item) only.

Comment: @Saravanan: No, the question is not about changing for all such occurences.

Comment: @Saravanan I've answered what the OP has asked for.

Comment: I can confirm that this indeed answers my question.